# QtCreator 7.0.0 crashes with Qt version 5.15.2

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator, qt5.15

I am QtCreator 7.0.0 for my Android developments. I am able to execute the app on QtCreator when I select version 5.12.9 for compilation. However, when I switch to Qt 5.15.2 as soon as I hit execute button the application crashes.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find any way or the reason of this crash. Could you help me to understand this crash so I can try to fix if it is something related to system settings?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you debug your application instead of running it in the IDE?

Comment: You mean just compiling the project? If yes, there is no crash in that case. Seems some problem with this version because just now I downgraded the Qtcreator and things seems to be working with Qt 5.15.2

Answer (score 1):

This combo does work for me on **Windows 10** (I.e. Qt for Android v5.15.2 + Creator v7) - but on **LINUX** (i.e. Ubuntu 20.04) it fails!  Compilation succeeds, but deployment crashes Creator.

I tried the Creator v8 beta, to see if that new version fixed this but that didn't work either...

So... I installed Creator v5.0.3 **along side** my regular Qt installation (with Creator v7), and that worked! You can get it here: https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/5.0/5.0.3/

> Note: Qt went totally nuts in the last year, pumping out one major
> version of Creator after another for some crazy reason.  They were only on v4 after 25+ years and
> then they dumped 4 new major versions on us in like 1 year!! What the
> hell is the story with that?! Anyway, I think Creator v5 is the safest
> bet for Qt v5.x.  For Qt6, you probably want to be on the latest and
> greatest Creator version (whatever happens to be at the time you're
> reading this!).